# Printer not installing in ubuntu. Can one install alternative drivers?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, scanner, canon

I have recently purchased a printer and found that the provider apparently does not provide drivers for it in Linux[(Canon PIXMA G2411)](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_g_series/pixma-g2411.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=).

Is there perhaps some 3rd party software I could use to get around this or a solution to this issue?

**Exact model:** Canon PIXMA G2411

**Serial number:** KMBG97376

**Operating system:** Ubuntu 20.04

I did find this link online ,[Canon Image Drivers: Canon PIXMA G2411](https://www.canonimagedrivers.com/canon-pixma-g2411-drivers-download/) , but I was unable to download the drivers. Has anyone had a similar problem and if so how did they solve it?

Comment: The website referred to doesn't seem to work. Have you tries this one? https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_g_series/pixma-g3411.html?type=setup

Comment: @Bernard Decock The link given is for a G3411. Canon do not appear to offer Linux support for the G2411 at that website.

Comment: @Sonji Please provide the outputs of `systemctl list-units "ippusbxd" | grep service` and `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`. Edit your first post to have them there.

Comment: With 18.04 or later, driverless printing is used. Specific driver should not be required. If printer works with Mac or Windows it should just work. My Brother printer immediately comes up on live installer. https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting

Comment: systemctl list-units "ippusbxd" | grep service should be systemctl list-units "ippusbxd*" | grep service. Note the missing *.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Update the repositories:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install required packages:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc libtool libssl-dev libc-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libpng-dev libtiff5-dev cups
```

Download GutenPrint source:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-print/files/gutenprint-5.3/5.3.3/gutenprint-5.3.3.tar.xz/download
```

Unzip file:

```
 cd ~/home/user/Downloads
 tar -xvf gutenprint-5.3.3.tar.xz
```

Build and install Gutenprint:

```
 cd ~/home/user/Downloads/gutemprint-5.3.3
 ./configure
 make
 sudo make install
```

Open your browser and type in the navigation bar:

```
 http://localhost:631
```

Log on to the CUPS web interface as "admin".

In the CUPS web interface, choose "Do Administration Tasks"

Then choose "Add a New Printer"

Answer (score 0):

It takes awhile for printers to be in the SAMBA/CUPS printer list that comes up when adding a new printer.  To this day, my Canon iX6820 is off color on Ubuntu 16.04 however colors are better on Ubuntu 20.04.  The printer in my case is native to XP and network-available to the Ubuntu systems.  By adding new printer, I speak of accessing the printer rather that preparing a system to host the printer.

I'm in the US - I asked Canon support about driving the printer from Ubuntu.  Canon didn't support driving the iX6820 from Ubuntu however, somehow I was able to get into Canon support for the printer from Asia (Australia) where it is/was supported on Linux systems.  From Canon's Australian support site, I did acquire the drivers needed for native Ubuntu support of the new printer.